# How to prevent VSCode's Select All (Ctrl+A) from moving the cursor to the bottom of the current file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I select all text in the editor (Ctrl+A), the code does not scroll down to the bottom, however the cursor does. When I press Escape and I want to continue writing code, I'd like the cursor to be at the same position it was before.
What happens right now is: when I press Escape, the code scrolls all the way down. I then have to find the previous cursor position.

Comment: instead of pressing Esc press Arrow-Left or Arrow-Right to move to begin or end of selection, Esc moves to the Active point of the selection

Comment: with Ctrl+A you lose the anchor/active location of the previous selection, current anchor at `(1,1)` and active at `(last-line,last-char)`

Comment: Just hit `Ctrl-U` undo twice after the `Escape`.